# Show whether the series converge or diverge and find its limit

Tags: sequences-and-series

Show whether the series $\sum^\infty_{k=0} {4 \over {3^k}}$ converge or diverge. In case of convergence, try to determine (and prove) the sum of the series.

Used ratio test, so ${|x_n+1 \over |x_n| }= {{4 \over 3^{n+1}} \over {4 \over 3^n}} = {4 \over 3^{n+1}} *{3^n \over4} = {1 \over 3} = :q < 1$

Hence $|x_{n+1}| <= q|x_n|$ - so the series converges.
Let's find its limit:
$ S = {a \over 1 -r } (r = {1 \over3}, a = 4 )$

$  S = { 4 \over 1 - {1 \over 3}} = 4 * {3 \over 2} = 6 $

I'm not sure if it's correct?

Comment: You are correct, you don't need to use ratio test as you can just observe that it is a geometric series with first term $4$ and ratio $\frac{1}{3}$, so the series has value $\frac{4}{1-\frac{1}{3}}=6$ as you pointed out, so you are correct.

Comment: how to count $ r = {1 \over 3}$ without ratio test?

Comment: You can observe that $r=\frac13$ right from the series but using the ratio test to determine that is fine too.